# What should I use instead of "menschenwelt"?

Tags: difference, word-choice, noun, gender-neutrality

I am doing a review on Marx's  "Ökonomisch-philosophische Manuskripte" and I must write about the *Menschenwelt*, but I do not think "the man world" is a suitable term for 2017. I need to change it either to *Personenwelt* or *Leutewelt* , but I am not a German speaker, so I do not know which one is better in this context.

Many thanks from Brazil.

Comment: "Mensch" in gender neutral, if that is what you are concerned about.

Comment: You mean you are really, really(?) considering changing the wordings of a source to fit your or someone elses needs????!!!

Comment: "Mensch" means *human being* rather than *male person* as you seem to assume. And *Personen-* or *Leutewelt* would be utter nonsense.

Comment: And it wouldn't matter anyway if Mensch indeed had meant "male". You simply CANNOT change a source, that is not in par with scientific principles.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use it? will the review be in English or in German or Portugese?

Comment: @Beta: they are currently cleaning old books from "racist" wording, so why stop there?

Comment: @Janka, I know this, and I call such a behaviour revisionary. In my view unaccepable, but the more scolars who find this OK, the more acceptable it will be with time, I realize that. Then there really is no limit to what you can change, this year it is something, next year there's something else.

Comment: The "world of men" (perhaps with a little footnote) would work well, even today, given that it's a historic text. (It's in fact the usual translation, if a quick search is to be trusted.) Or, you know, use as is: it's a foreign word after all, you explain it once and then use untranslated.

Comment: @Oliver-Grimm it is in Portuguese. The translation shows  "o mundo do homem" (the men world) where it could fit "o mundo civil" (the civil world)or "o mundo da humanidade" (the humankind world) or "o mundo humano" (the human world) or "o mundo das pessoas" (the people's world) or anything not 1844 mysoginist. Portuguse and other latim-based languages are extremely gender binary and masculine, since created by man in the past, and simply writing "the men world" leaves 1/2 of the world population out of it. This was the problem with the translation. And again, thanks from Brazil. :)

Comment: @Beta My review, my up to dating the facts, my use of words to include myself and all the other 1/2 world population to the considerations of the mysoginist Marx. The problem is with my portguese language rather than with the german one, since this is gender-neutral and that extremely gender bynary. I will leave it up to my teacher to discuss the modification. I'm happy to see the word is usable, so only the translation is now coming with a note "I here used a more 21st century language,freed from bynarims so present in the past".
And again, thanks, from Brazil, for the elucidation.

Comment: @Ingmar yep, footnote for the win! But what I was avoiding was specifically the usage of "world of men" haha I used, I believe the translation to english is "world of people" (or "people's world"? now I lost the track on the English grammar).Thanks to Gerhard and Hubert Schölnast, for the happiness of Beta, the source is unchanged, but my translation does not leave 1/2 of the world out of it.

Comment: Oh, and @tofro I don't speak a single word in german. So yeah, I obviously assumed things based on what showed up on bab. la and priberam  dictionaries. My portuguese language is extremely gender bynary, wich I now see here does not necessarily applies to german, lucky germans!haha I submitted it keeping the german, gender neutral source, and used a gender neutral translation with a footnote that goes "I here used a more 21st century language, freed from the bynarims that were so present in the past". Oh, the footnote was also a critic to Marx's Capitalists x employees argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of the German word »Mensch«:

- der Mensch = human being (of any gender)
- der Mann = man (a male human)

Comment: Thank you! It must be the translation to portuguese rather than the english one, then. Portuguese, as well as many other latim-based languages is extremely gender binary, and it is clear to me and many many others that the language used on the old sociology [and any text, actually...] is misogynist, just so, the translation in portuguese goes as "the man world" instead of "the people/human world". Being a gender neutral enthusiast around here is hard.
And again, many thanks from Brazil!

Answer (score -1):

Die Welt der Menschen oder unsere heutige Welt.

Comment: what is wrong using one of this options instead?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but: The answer would be OK if the OP had not asked the question under a false assumption.